# How to get a Sum of selected Number value from two edit texts

Tags: java, android, calculator

I have two editText like first edit text we are entering some number like 12324582... In that value we are searching one number from first editText... that is second editText... And I have one button and one textView...

Whenever I click the button, the result will get the sum of the searching number displayed on the textview.

For example:

EditText1= 12345252 (There are three 2's)

I want to search 2 number

EditText2= 2

Whenever I click the button, the textView shows the number 6 (2+2+2).

Comment: Please add an actual (pseudo?)code example as it's currently quite unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I don't have logic

Comment: Well that's not so nice but I don't see how that's relevant to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


EditText edtInput, edtSearch, edtOutPut;
Button btnCalculate;
int lastIndex = 0;
int count = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    edtInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtInput);
    edtSearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtSearch);
    edtOutPut = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtOutPut);

    btnCalculate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate);

    btnCalculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count=0;
            lastIndex = 0;
            calculate();
        }
    });
}

private void calculate() {
    while(lastIndex != -1){

        lastIndex = edtInput.getText().toString().indexOf(edtSearch.getText().toString(),lastIndex);

        if(lastIndex != -1){
            count ++;
            lastIndex += edtSearch.getText().toString().length();
        }
    }
    edtOutPut.setText(""+(count*Integer.parseInt(edtSearch.getText().toString())));
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use StringUtils class from apache.common.lang.
All you need to do is count number of occurence number from EditText2 in EditText1.
So use use this method:

```
int count = StringUtils.countMatches(TextEdit1.getText(), TextEdit2.getText());
```

After that set text in textView which is multiply number of occurence and number from EditText2

```
textView.setText(Integer.toString(count * Integer.parseInt(TextEdit2.getText()))
```

Comment: I didn't find a StringUtils class in Android Studio

Comment: It's not a Java class so you have to add dependency to apache common lang